# Prolog CLPFD trying to define domain for lists of list

Tags: list, prolog, constraint-programming, clpfd

I am working on a constraints programming problem in Prolog and I am having problems trying to define a domain for lists of list. The initial challenge of the problem is as follows:

```
   trains([[1,2,0,1], %from station, to station, departs at, arrives at
           [2,3,4,5],
           [2,3,0,1],
           [3,4,5,6],
           [3,4,2,3],
           [3,4,8,9]]).

   threepath(A,D,Ps):-
        Ps = [[A,B, _T0, T1], [B,C, T2, T3], [C,D, T4, _T5]],
        T2 #> T1,
        T4 #> T3,
        trains(Ts),
        tuples_in(Ps, Ts).
```

After that, I am expected to expand on this to accommodate for any number of trains instead of only 3. Here is my attempt at doing that:

```
  anypath(A,D,Ps,N):-
        length(Ps,N),
        Ps ins Xs,
        Xs = [A,B,C,D],
        Xs ins 1..9. %How to define the domain for a list of length 4 inside a list of variable length.
```

However, I am not very sure how to define a domain for lists of list. So far, I have defined length(Ps, N) so that Ps can have any length. Then, I tried to define the variables inside of Ps so that they will be list of length 4 but failed horribly.

Additionally, I am also not sure how to define the constraints for a variable length of Ps like the 3 scenario case where T2 #> T1 and T3 #> T4. The pattern that I am seeing is the last element of the next list should be greater than the third element of the list before it but I am stuck on the syntax to represent this constraint as well.

Right now, I am trying to use recursion to somehow set the Head of Ps to a list of length 4 and to recurse through to do the same with the tails since I won't be able to know how long the list Ps will be.

I would be grateful if someone can shed some light on this.

**Update on Progress 25/3/2015**

I read on an example of another problem that a maplist was used to produce inner lists. An excerpt of the code is:

```
length_(Length, List) :- length(List, Length).

child_row(X) :- X ins 1..16 .

ww(X) :-
        write(X),
        write('/').

print_row(Row) :-
        maplist(ww, Row),
        nl.

children(Class) :-
        length(Class, 4),
        maplist(length_(4), Class),
        maplist(child_row , Class),
```

From what I understand, maplist(length_(4), Class) applies the length_(4) to every element inside Class and creates inner lists of length 4 as a result. So, I tried to apply this to my problem and here is my attempt:

```
length_(Length, List) :- length(List, Length).
anypath(A,D,Ps,N):-
    length(Ps,N),
    maplist(length_(4), Ps),
    %constraint(Ps),
    trains(Ts),
    tuples_in(Ps, Ts).
```

However, I get an error message saying "length/2: Type error: `list' expected, found`4'" regardless of whether N is set to 3 or 4 and I don't quite understand this as well since it should work the same way as the example above and gtrace is a bit messy to detect what's wrong for me.

I am currently stuck at the moment and I will update if I figure anything out.

So, I have another question that I hope can be answered is "What is the normal practice of creating inner lists and how do you normally do it yourself?".

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do the `Ps ins Xs` when `Xs` isn't instantiated. You could try, `Xs = [A,B,C,D], Xs ins 1..9, label(Xs), Ps ins Xs`.

Comment: I tried it out but it gives me  `Domain Error: 'clpfd-domain' expeceted, found '[1,1,1,1]'`. I made added constraints 'B #> A' since I am going from one station to another and 'T0 > T1' since time will pass and it increases when I travel. Here's my updated code with your suggestion: `anypath(A,D,Ps,N):-
 length(Ps,N),
 Xs = [A, B, T0, T1],
 Xs ins 1..9,
 label(Xs),
 Ps ins Xs,
 B #> A,
 T1 #> T0,
 trains(Ts),
 tuples_in(Ps, Ts).`

Comment: Gah sorry, my suggestion for the `Ps ins Xs` was dumb...

Comment: Create a predicate, say, `define_foo(X) :- length(X, 4), X ins 1..9.`, then do `length(P, N), maplist(define_foo, P)`. Then `P` will be a list of length `N`, consisting of elements of length 4 which are domain variables `ins 1..9`.

Comment: I tried a different way since the post using maplist from another problem I saw involving the use of length to define the inner lists but it has not worked as well. I updated my post detailing my attempt and I appreciate if you could take a look at it whenever you are free. :D

Comment: Oh! it seems like you replied while I was typing my comment. I am going to test out your suggestion now. Thanks.

Comment: It works! Now I am confused about something. Why does my 2nd attempt using a similar method with maplist to the one you suggested not working?

Comment: Your `length_/2` predicate and `maplist` usage look OK. Are you sure what you tried is what you typed into your question?

Comment: Hmm, I am pretty sure I tried what a typed since it was done in gtrace. Oddly enough, now it works after I restart Prolog, probably I reloaded too many times or something. Thanks for helping me btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten the list with

```
append(Trains, FlatTrains)
```

and then constrain the domain of FlatTrains

```
FlatTrains ins 1..9
```

Comment: s(X)! `append/2` is a good way to remove exactly one level of nesting.